# How to rectify private error while using Friend Function in C++?

Tags: c++

Getting this error while using friend function in C++  : error: ‘int complex::a’ is private within this context. How will I rectify this error? I have created one complex class and while learning a friend function, i get to know that friend function can access private member functions too. But in this code, this error pops out. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class complex{

private:
    int a, b;

public:
    void setNumber(int x,int y){a=x;b=y;}
    void getNumber(){cout << "\n a="<< a << "b=" << b; }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, complex);
    friend istream& operator >>(istream&, complex&);


};

ostream& operator <<(ostream &dout, complex c){

    cout << "a=" << c.a;
    cout << "b=" << c.b;


return (dout);
}

istream& operator <<(istream &din, complex &c){

  cin>>c.a>>c.b;

return (din);
}


int main(){

complex c1;
cin >> c1;
cout << c1;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You friend one `operator>>` and one `operator<<`, but declare two global `operator<<` functions.  So one of them is not a friend.

Comment: Okey Thankyou so much. I have mistyped extraction operator symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
  ostream& operator <<(ostream &dout, complex c)
  {
    cout << "a=" << c.a;
    cout << "b=" << c.b;
    return (dout);
  }

  istream& operator <<(istream &din, complex &c)
  {
   cin>>c.a>>c.b;
   return (din);
  }
```

to

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &dout, const complex& c)
{
    dout << "a=" << c.a;
    dout << "b=" << c.b;
    return (dout);
}

istream& operator >>(istream &din, complex &c)
{
    din>>c.a>>c.b;
    return (din);
}
```